# Converging Pandas Dataframe so that a column only has one value but its other column values are summed up

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas Dataframe as so:

```
fruits = ['apple', 'apple', 'banana', 'banana', 'orange']
quantities = [10, 5, 20, 12, 25]
products = pd.DataFrame({'Fruits': fruits, 'Amount': quantities})
```

What I want to do is converge the `'Fruits'` column so that the only entries are

```
'apple', 'banana', and 'orange'
```

but their 'quantities' are added up, i.e.

```
'apple'=15, 'banana'=32, and 'orange'=25.
```

This would be the new dataframe.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Groupby:

```
In [4]: products
Out[4]: 
   Amount  Fruits
0      10   apple
1       5   apple
2      20  banana
3      12  banana
4      25  orange

[5 rows x 2 columns]

In [5]: products.groupby('Fruits').sum()
Out[5]: 
        Amount
Fruits        
apple       15
banana      32
orange      25

[3 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: This is good, however is there a way to still keep 2 columns?

Comment: call `reset_index()` on the output from [5] if you need to.

Comment: I just did as_index=False for the options in groupby

Answer (score 1):

You should consider making a dictionary as follows:

```
my_dict = {}
for i,item in enumerate(fruits):
    if item in my_dict:
        my_dict[item] += quantities[i]
    else:
        my_dict[item] = quantities[i]
```

Then you can simply do:

```
products = pd.DataFrame({'Fruits': my_dict.keys(), 'Amount': my_dict.values()})
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Neither `dict.keys()` nor `dict.values()` can guarantee order. Thus this will potentially screw up the data.

Comment: @msvalkon, Actually, it gives relatively correct values. I tested it. But, great catch.

Comment: Sure, for this dataset. But consider when you have millions of fruits.

Comment: @msvalkon, It is not a problem since the dictionary keys maintain value with their respective values. Also when getting `keys` and `values`, the list is returned as is. I also just finished testing this for 1000+ elements, works. (I was able to check because I new the way I have created the values)

Comment: It is a problem, the order of the keys and values the respective methods return is arbitrary, you cannot depend on it for any real scenario. Here's from the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries): *The keys() method of a dictionary object returns a list of all the keys used in the dictionary, in arbitrary order*.